# How to set individual mysqld parameters using the bitnami/mysql Helm chart?

Tags: mysql, bitnami, helm

We're using the [bitnami/mysql Helm chart](https://github.com/bitnami/charts/tree/main/bitnami/mysql).

We'd like to upgrade `max_allowed_packet` from the default `16M` value to `64M`.

From what I can read in the [README](https://github.com/bitnami/charts/tree/main/bitnami/mysql#mysql-primary-parameters), it looks like the only way to pass custom `[mysqld]` parameters is by overriding the `primary.configuration` value.

But the default value is quite big:

```
$ helm show values bitnami/mysql
```

```
...
primary:
  ...
  configuration: |-
    [mysqld]
    default_authentication_plugin=mysql_native_password
    skip-name-resolve
    explicit_defaults_for_timestamp
    basedir=/opt/bitnami/mysql
    plugin_dir=/opt/bitnami/mysql/lib/plugin
    port=3306
    socket=/opt/bitnami/mysql/tmp/mysql.sock
    datadir=/bitnami/mysql/data
    tmpdir=/opt/bitnami/mysql/tmp
    max_allowed_packet=16M
    bind-address=*
    pid-file=/opt/bitnami/mysql/tmp/mysqld.pid
    log-error=/opt/bitnami/mysql/logs/mysqld.log
    character-set-server=UTF8
    collation-server=utf8_general_ci
    slow_query_log=0
    slow_query_log_file=/opt/bitnami/mysql/logs/mysqld.log
    long_query_time=10.0

    [client]
    port=3306
    socket=/opt/bitnami/mysql/tmp/mysql.sock
    default-character-set=UTF8
    plugin_dir=/opt/bitnami/mysql/lib/plugin

    [manager]
    port=3306
    socket=/opt/bitnami/mysql/tmp/mysql.sock
    pid-file=/opt/bitnami/mysql/tmp/mysqld.pid
...
```

So I would have to copy/paste this whole config block, just to modify one line.

**Is there a better way to modify just one `[mysqld]` configuration value?**

Comment: Maybe it allows a second config file?  It would need 2 lines:  `[mysqld]` and `max_allowed_packet=64M`.

Comment: @RickJames Not as far as a I can see I'm afraid!

Comment: Can you backup your bitnami/mysql and edit the file directly for the line to be changed then save it?  Stop/Start the instance and you will be done.   Some people are successful with cd bitnami then cp mysql 202305042014mysql to have a last running backup.  You may find the filename is actually mysql.cnf or mysql.ini be careful.